# How to find usage of c# indexer method in Visual Studio (with Resharper)

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

For example in `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`,

```
TValue this[TKey key] { get; set; }
```

How to find usage of `get` or `set`, or both?

Comment: It seems to be working if one put caret to after `]` at a calling site, but not anywhere on the definition line.

Comment: It works when key is not a variable name, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the caret on `get` or `set` to just get usages of the getter or setter respectively. Or place the caret on `this` to find either.